# What does it mean to be advanced in html and css?

Tags: html, css

I have seen a job offer, that requires both and I am not sure what it means. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably means that you should have a good knowledge of these languages when you apply for that job offer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming problem; it's an employment question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page helps: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/14972

You're looking at the second paragraph -- intermediate level.

Answer (score 0):

Advanced means you should have very good knowledge in both of the HTML and CSS. What else would it mean :)

Comment: Well, I know the question sounds rather idiotic. :D I just wanted to know what it entails regarding particular CSS/HTML skills.